# pm2 running on EC2 using jenkins not working?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, amazon-ec2, pm2

I am running my node application on AWS EC2 server. 
For continuous integration I installed Jenkins, on EC2, jenkins polls a code commit continuously and when a commit occurs executes some commands written in a script.

The last command is

**pm2 start server.js**

Everything works fine and the build is shown successful but later when I access the URL the site doesn't show.

I have a nginx server in front of node server, it gives 
**502 Bad Gateway**

On checking I realised the node application is not running, so I cehcked pm2 logs and found this happening -

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: [[[[ PM2/God daemon launched ]]]]**

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: BUS system [READY] on port /var/lib/jenkins/.pm2/pub.sock**

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: RPC interface [READY] on port /var/lib/jenkins/.pm2/rpc.sock**

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:server id:0**

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: App name:server id:0 online**

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: pm2 has been killed by signal, dumping process list before exit...**

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: Deleting process 0**

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: Stopping app:server id:0**

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: App [server] with id [0] and pid [25822], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]**

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: Proc is not defined anymore or is being killed**

**2016-08-12 07:53:28: [PM2] Exited peacefully**

pm2 is getting killed as soon as starting, don't know why, tried reinstalling pm2 from npm didn't work.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Node   v4.4.7 LTS

npm    v2.15.8

pm2    v1.1.3

Work is halted, need help immediately, please.

Comment: Does it help if you ask it nicely at the beginning of your shell step:`export BUILD_ID=dontKillMePlease` :)

Comment: It worked. Why was that happening any idea. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the comments given by Dusan Bajic, if anyone is doing continous integration with jenkins on EC2 using a node application and similar thing happens with pm2 just add this line in script before starting pm2.

**export BUILD_ID=dontKillMePlease**

and instead of

**pm2 start server.js**

use

**pm2 restart server.js**

server.js being your application or else build will fail if in jenkins if you commit and it runs script again cause pm2 is already running server.js and won't stop.

Comment: Hi. I'm having the same issue and my jenkins shell is just a command to execute `./deploy.sh`. I tried both `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe ./deploy.sh` and `BUILD_ID=dontKillMePlease ./deploy.sh` but it still doesn't help ( still having problem with `502 Bad Gateway`). I checked PM2 log after the build but there is nothing like `pm2 has been killed by signal ...`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It's working for me but I had to go to Jenkins project Configuration and in my build step (execute shell) I had to write `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe ./build.sh`. Don't use it in the build.sh script itself - I thought I needed to put BUILD_ID on the line where I'm starting the daemon that's being killed but you actually have to put BUILD_ID on the whole script inside the Jenkins config. Though that's weird `export` didn't work for me - maybe using it without 'please' would work

Answer (score 1):

From [ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller)

> To reliably kill processes spawned by a job during a build, Jenkins
> contains a bit of native code to list up such processes and kill them

...

> **How it works**
>
> The ProcessTreeKiller takes advantage of the fact that by
> default a new process gets a copy of the environment variables of its
> spawning/creating process.
>
> It sets a specific environment variable in the process executing the
> build job. Later, when the user requests to stop the build job's
> process it gets a list of all processes running on the computer and
> their environment variables, and looks for the environment variable
> that it initially set for the build job's process.
>
> Every job with that environment variable in its environment is then
> terminated.
>
> **If your build wants to leave a daemon running behind...**
>
> A convenient way to achieve that is to change the environment variable
> BUILD_ID which Jenkins's ProcessTreeKiller is looking for. This will
> cause Jenkins to assume that your daemon is not spawned by the Jenkins
> build. For example:
>
> `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe /usr/apache/bin/httpd`

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version of Jenkins, the **BUILD_ID is deprecated**. Instead use **JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe**

In my Jenkinsfiles, I have used it like below

```
stage('Run') {
            steps {
                script {
                   sh 'export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe; pm2 --name SampleApp start npm -- start'
                }
            }
        }
```

If you are invoking a shell script, then add JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe in the shell script file.